# Twilio mms from an Android phone within Canada using Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, twilio, mms

**Target Platform** : Samsung S6 - Android

**Development base** : Unity3D using C#

**Intention** :

Send a picture (MMS) shot within an app to any desired phone number within Canada. This app is supposed to be preloaded to a single Samsung S6.

**Questions** :

- I was unable to find any Unity samples within you SDK, however I was wondering if anyone knows Unity samples for my intended use. However planned to use these [scripts as first of reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest).
- Though the Android Phone number which is used to send MMS can be associated with Twilio the receiver would have **no** association with Twilio as the sender phone number is not something we would know until the photo is taken - hence is this a concern?
- I see that from from the API [call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest)

  ```
      // Send a new outgoing MMS by POSTing to the Messages resource */
  client.SendMessage(
      "YYY-YYY-YYYY", // From number, must be an SMS-enabled Twilio number
      person.Key,     // To number, if using Sandbox see note above
      // message content
      string.Format("Hey {0}, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!", person.Value),
      // media url of the image
      new string[] {"https://demo.twilio.com/owl.png" }
  );
  ```

  the fourth and final parameter is a URL link. Can link of the image be from any server or should it only be from twilio's server?

**Thank you very much for time.** Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here you are](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms). As far as I know this works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks @Alex I prefer to stick twilio and if things don't work on that horizon - then I will try use that lib. It is really though, I have to say.